# Movie about the last member of a man-like dead species

Tags: identify-this-movie

I heard the plot for this movie from a friend.  Humans are homo sapiens, but historically there have been other species in the homo genus, neanderthal being one of them.  Perhaps the movie is about a member of the homo neanderthals, but it could be about some of the other branches of the gene homo.

In any case, the plot is about the last member of such species, and his search for other "people" like him after his tribe gets killed off.  But he finds no one.  The last scene has him throwing a stick into the sea in frustration (or is it despair?).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Missing Link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095646/combined) from 1988. From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_Link_%28film%29):

> **The film follows the last of the man-apes** (Peter Elliott) as he wanders through the wilderness after his tribe is slaughtered by the aggressive humans who have invented the ax and have learned to make use of fire.

And in the end:

> When he comes across a human footprint at the ocean shore, he sniffs it and then starts hitting it, wanting revenge against the humans. But he then relents **and tosses the ax into the ocean**.

Here's the trailer: